# Sequence associated with degrees of graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

A sequence $(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is said to be a graphic sequence if there exists a simple graph $G$ such that the degrees of $G$ are exactly $d_1,\ldots,d_n$. If $D$ is a graphic sequence such that $d_1 \geq \cdots \geq d_n$, then:

- $\sum_{i=1}^n  d_i$ is even
- $\sum_{i=1}^k d_i \leq k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \min(k,d_i)$

I could easily prove the first property since I've used the fact that if $m$ is the number of edges of $G$, then $$\sum_{v \in G} d(v) = 2m$$

Now, I've tried to show that the second property holds with an inductive proof but I got stuck in the inductive step: if $(d_1,\ldots,d_{n+1})$ is a graphic sequence and $d_{n+1}$ is odd, then I cannot apply the inductive hypothesis on $(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ since its sum is odd.

Any ideas to prove this property ? Maybe there is an alternative solution without induction, I would appreciate if someone could give me any suggestions. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ be vertices of degree $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$ in a graph with this degree sequence, and let $S = \{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k\}$. Write $\deg_S(v_i)$ for the number of neighbors a vertex has in $S$.
$$
   \sum_{i=1}^k d_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \deg_S(v_i)
$$
by double-counting: both sides count the number of endpoints all edges of the graph have in $S$.

To prove the inequality
$$\sum_{i=1}^k d_i \leq k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \min\{k,d_i\},$$ 
it's enough to show that
$$
   \deg_S(v_i) \le \begin{cases}
      k-1 & v_i \in S \\
      \min\{k,d_i\} & v_i \notin S
   \end{cases}
$$
and apply this bound to every vertex.